# download and upload facebook profile photo

Tags: php

I`m new in  API field.

How can I log in facebook and download\upload profile picture with php?

Answer (score 0):

There is a excelent Pear Package 
http://pear.php.net/package/Services_Facebook

and also have a look at the developers wiki of facebook

http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/PHP

Comment: I don`t understand.I must create new Facebook application??

Answer (score 0):

I can't answer to the download part, but you are unable to upload a profile photo through Facebooks's API. You'd have to hack around it... fake login etc but I expect that would be very difficult.